# Updating a Dataframe row by a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've already seen the [Replace a row by a new Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54183019/replace-a-row-by-a-new-dataframe) solution, but It's pretty unclear to me.

I've got a `DataFrame` of results of some model with a `MultiIndex` at the name of the model and the mode (train/test) that I want to update with the last execution keeping the other model results (create the `DataFrame` if it doesn't exist or update the row with the same name and mode with the `dic` variable). Here is my code:

```
def save_results(dic, path = "../ModelsResults"):
    try:
        df_results = pd.read_pickle(path)
        print("Updating ModelResults...")
        df_now = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([dic])
        if df_results.index.isin([(dic["Model"], dic["Mode"])]).any():
            print("\tUpdating Model/Mode...")
            df_now.drop(["Model", "Mode"],axis=1)
            df_results.at[dic["Model"], dic["Mode"]] = df_now
        else:
            print("\tCreating Model/Mode...")
            df_results = df_results.append(df_now)


    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Creating ModelResults...")
        df_results = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([dic])
        df_results = df_results.set_index(["Model", "Mode"])

    df_results.to_pickle(path)
    print("Done")
    return df_results
```

Every metric that I want to save is in the `dic` variable. For example:

```
dic = {
    "Model": "Dummy-PredictingAlwaysZero",
    "Mode": "Train",
    "MSE": mse ,
    "nRMSE": nrmse,
    "nDCG@10": ndcg(train["rel"].values, y_pred, k = 10),
    "nDCG@50": ndcg(train["rel"].values, y_pred, k = 50)
}
df_results = save_results(dic, path = "./ModelsResults")
```

And the expected `DataFrame` is like:

```
                                      MSE   nDCG@10   nDCG@50     nRMSE
Model                      Mode                                        
Dummy-PredictingAlwaysZero Train  0.08639  0.162948  0.106816  0.293922
```

Comment: Can you provide your sample DataFrame input, sample dictionary and desired DataFrame output? It is pretty hard to visualise the structure you are trying to obtain without those. Thanks

Comment: I have not got an output yet, but I could describe it here:  The columns would be metrics such as Accuracy, Recall, etc... and the MultiIndex values the Model (String such as Deep, Recurrent, etc...) and the Mode (whether is in train or test mode). Sorry it's not clear.

Comment: I'm asking you to provide a sample of how your output will look like in a table form. It is difficult as it is to understand text. You dont have to provide the full output, but enough output for us to identify what the pattern is, so that we can formulate a code to achieve it.

Comment: There you have the expected output DataFrame. Sorry for that.